# Equivalent of Swift trailing closure in C++

Tags: c++, swift, lambda, closures

In Swift when we need to pass a closure as a parameter of a function, if the closure is the last parameter to pass we can specify the closure body after the last parenthesis `)` of the calling function, that is called a trailing closure.

Swift example:

```
func someFunctionThatTakesAClosure(closure: () -> Void) {
    // function body goes here
}

// Here's how you call this function without using a trailing closure:

someFunctionThatTakesAClosure(closure: {
    // closure's body goes here
})

// Here's how you call this function with a trailing closure instead:

someFunctionThatTakesAClosure() {
    // trailing closure's body goes here
}
```

sometimes in C++, when I use std::sort and I pass a closure, the code would be more readable if I used an equivalent of a Swift trailing closure.
I have very little experience with C++ standards newer than C++11, do you know if there is there anything similar in C++?

Comment: Can you post what you would like to do in `C++` for a real (working) example?

Comment: No, and C++ has different lambda syntax anyway, so it would introduce inconsistency.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This are the simplest C++ equivalents:

```
void someFunctionThatTakesAClosure(std::function<void()> closure) {
    // function body goes here
}

someFunctionThatTakesAClosure([] {
    // code comes here
});
```

C++ do not predict something like trailing closure.

Note that in C++ there block [(lambda) capturing is not implicit](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda) like in Swift or Objective C, you have to should state what should be captured:

```
int copyVar = 0;
int refVar = 1;
someFunctionThatTakesAClosure([copyVar, &refVar] {
    // code comes here
    refVar += copyVar;
});
```

There is also a wild capture which will make it work like in Swift or Objective C, but from my experience it is much better to state what and how is captured, in many cases it saved me from creating unwanted reference cycle, what happen to me sometimes in Objective C (implicit `self` use).

Note that in Objective C++ blocks can be used as C++ argument, so this will work too:

```
someFunctionThatTakesAClosure(^{
    // mixed C++/Objective C code comes here
});
```

More advanced approach involves use of C++ templates, but I don't think you need that.